# Form validation in JSP and Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP and servlet, could you help me for form validation like to check weather text field is empty or not, in an easy way.
Thank you!

Comment: JSP is nothing but a part of HTML. you can put validations in <script> tag under <head> tag.!!

Comment: Read book: "Java Servlet & JSP Cookbook", page 274, using JavaScript to Validate Form Values in a Servlet
(validate at server-side) (You can read this section in Google books free: https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=j8wSW13lHh4C)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the validation both at client side and server side. You can use either JavaScript or JQuery to validate at client side.

Here are the references for them:

- [Using JQuery](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/jquery/formValidation.html)
- [Using JavaScript](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml)

Here is the example which explains how to handle form post data at the server side using Servlet:

```
<form action="formpost" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Write the servlet reads the post parameters and validates them:

```
public class FormPost extends HttpServlet
{
 protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, 
   HttpServletResponse responst) throws ServletException, IOException
 {

   if(request.getParameter("name") != null){
      String nameParameter = request.getParameter("name");
   } else {
       //write you validation code here
   }

   int ageParameter = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));



 }

}
```

Comment: does single servlet works for all of the form of the project?

Comment: Why? do you want to such validation for multiple servlets?

Comment: i need validation in all form of my project.so single servlets can Be used for multiple form o jsp

Comment: In that case, you should be doing this using Filter. And apply the filter for the Jsps required.

Answer (score 0):

If purely using JSP and Servlet, i recommend springing off from JavaScript abstraction libraries like `JQuery` for this task.

Such is the bassistance plugin
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: in terms of validation, both client side validate and server side validate should be considered, so besides the Jquery to perform the client side validation, it is also necessary to do a double check for some important fields at server side as well.

Comment: Hi zinking. Question asked for "form validation".

Comment: well, my take for that is he is asking about general "validation"

Answer (score 0):

You can do client side input validation. I suggest to use [JQUery plugin for validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).